# importmap-rails + sprockets not finding stimulus-loading.js in fresh stimulus-rails installation

Tags: sprockets, ruby-on-rails-7, stimulusjs, import-maps, stimulus-rails

Mature app updating to Rails 7.0.7, Ruby 3.1.2, adding `stimulus-rails` using the installer, with `importmap-rails`, `turbo-rails` and `sprockets-rails` already installed. No custom Stimulus controllers yet, just trying to load the setup "out of the box".

I've read through a dozen Q/A's about this on StackOverflow, including Alex's lengthy and good explanations of how `importmap-rails` works, but none of them seem to explain this case.

When I boot the server locally, i'm getting

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stimulus-loading.js"):
```

Everything seems right in the importmap:

Here is the result of `./bin/importmap json`:

```rb
{
  "imports": {
    "application": "/assets/application.js",
    "@rails/ujs": "/assets/@rails--ujs.js",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "/assets/turbo.min.js",
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "/assets/stimulus.min.js",
    "@hotwired/stimulus-loading": "/assets/stimulus-loading.js",
    "controllers/application": "/assets/controllers/application.js",
    "controllers/hello_controller": "/assets/controllers/hello_controller.js",
    "controllers": "/assets/controllers/index.js"
  }
}
```

I have run `rails assets:clobber` as suggested in several answers. Here's the standard setup, these lines all added by the installers for `turbo-rails`, `importmap-rails` and `stimulus-rails` gems.

```rb
# config/importmap.rb

pin "application", preload: true
pin "@rails/ujs", to: "@rails--ujs.js" # @7.0.7
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
```

```rb
# application.js

import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import "@hotwired/stimulus"
import "@hotwired/stimulus-loading"
Rails.start(); import "controllers"
```

Here's my `assets/config/manifest.js`

```js
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_tree ../javascripts .js
//= link_tree ../../javascript .js
//= link_tree ../../../vendor/javascript .js

//= link my_application.js
```

I renamed `app/assets/javascripts/my_application.js` to avoid naming conflict with `app/javascript/application.js`

I've added `app/javascript` to the asset path (didn't seem to change anything)

```rb
# config/initializers/assets.rb

Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app/javascript")
```

I've added asset debugging and tried turning on/off compiling

```rb
# config/environments/development

config.assets.compile = true # if false, no assets found
config.assets.debug = true # didn't tell me anything new
```

Log of page load in dev mode:

```
Started GET "/assets/es-module-shims.min.js" for 10.0.2.2 at 2023-09-06 16:47:39 +0000
10.0.2.2 - - [06/Sep/2023:16:47:38 UTC] "GET /assets/es-module-shims.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
http://localhost:3000 -> /assets/es-module-shims.min.js
Started GET "/assets/BlackOnWhite.css" for 10.0.2.2 at 2023-09-06 16:47:40 +0000
Started GET "/assets/my_application.js" for 10.0.2.2 at 2023-09-06 16:47:41 +0000
10.0.2.2 - - [06/Sep/2023:16:47:38 UTC] "GET /assets/mo_application.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
http://localhost:3000 -> /assets/mo_application.js
10.0.2.2 - - [06/Sep/2023:16:47:38 UTC] "GET /assets/BlackOnWhite.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
http://localhost:3000 -> /assets/BlackOnWhite.css
Started GET "/assets/application.js" for 10.0.2.2 at 2023-09-06 16:47:42 +0000
10.0.2.2 - - [06/Sep/2023:16:47:42 UTC] "GET /assets/application.js HTTP/1.1" 200 367
http://localhost:3000 -> /assets/application.js
Started GET "/assets/stimulus.min.js" for 10.0.2.2 at 2023-09-06 16:47:44 +0000
Started GET "/assets/controllers/index.js" for 10.0.2.2 at 2023-09-06 16:47:44 +0000
Started GET "/assets/turbo.min.js" for 10.0.2.2 at 2023-09-06 16:47:45 +0000
10.0.2.2 - - [06/Sep/2023:16:47:43 UTC] "GET /assets/stimulus.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
http://localhost:3000 -> /assets/stimulus.min.js
Started GET "/assets/stimulus-loading.js" for 10.0.2.2 at 2023-09-06 16:47:46 +0000
10.0.2.2 - - [06/Sep/2023:16:47:43 UTC] "GET /assets/turbo.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
http://localhost:3000 -> /assets/turbo.min.js
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stimulus-loading.js"):
  
10.0.2.2 - - [06/Sep/2023:16:47:43 UTC] "GET /assets/stimulus-loading.js HTTP/1.1" 404 0
http://localhost:3000 -> /assets/stimulus-loading.js
10.0.2.2 - - [06/Sep/2023:16:47:43 UTC] "GET /assets/controllers/index.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
http://localhost:3000-> /assets/controllers/index.js
```

It seems from the log that there may be a path discrepancy between `/assets/stimulus-loading.js` and `/stimulus-loading.js`. But the browser is showing a 404 for `http://localhost:3000/assets/stimulus-loading.js`.

Comment: for your "path discrepancy" concern - update `sprockets` to `v4.2.1` - it's unrelated to your main issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

Occurred to me to check issues on the [stimulus-rails github page](https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus-rails/issues/108), and this is a known current issue, related to a [current Sprockets issue with 4.1.1](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/issues/749) where the hyphen in the name "stimulus-loading.js" makes Sprockets skip it because it thinks it's a digest.

The solution is setting `config.assets.digest = true` in `config/environments/development.rb`. According to the linked Stimulus issue, this is the Rails team's preferred setting for development, but it's been off in my legacy app since before my time.